# pass a cookie in angular component

Tags: .net, angular

I am creating an angular app that sits under iframe in .net application. I need to pass some data from .net application so angular app can do api calls as per requirements. How can I pass this data (such as a cookie or string value) from aspx page to angular component ?
one way to create cookie in .net code is

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(some_ cookie);
```

How can i access it in angular ? I tried using package 'angular2-cookie' like this but I always get some garbage value in angular.

```
this._cookieService.get(some_ cookie)
```

Comment: cookies aren't shared across iframes.  you'll have to embed the data in the html that encloses the angular app

Answer (score 0):

I've found the package of the link below very helpfull

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Stil... there are somethings you have to consider. The cookie you are creating on .net should have a name and a value. You must use the value to get this cookie in angular.

.NET

```
var some_cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(some_cookie);
```

angular

```
this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('cookie_name');
```

The other thing you should consider is that both application must be in the same domain. Check the application tab on chrome developer tools when testing for help if this is the problem ;)